# Separating methods into many controllers?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I noticed that many of the examples in the Laravel docs seem to have Controllers where the class has only one use/method.

For example, in [this part of the doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/hashing#basic-usage), they have a `UpdatePasswordController` class with a single method, `update()`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UpdatePasswordController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Update the password for the user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate the new password length...

        $request->user()->fill([
            'password' => Hash::make($request->newPassword)
        ])->save();
    }
}
```

Normally, I would put a method called `updatePassword()` in my `UserController` class (along with `signIn()`, `signUp()`, `resetPassword()`, etc.), but I'm wondering if it's better to create multiple classes, each with a single action?

Comment: That archicture is very subjetive. Usually controllers should handle too many actions associated to a specific context.

Comment: There are also [Single Action Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#single-action-controllers).

Answer (score 0):

Normally class is defined for a single purpose. In laravel , for authentication there is a Illuminate base bundle which is optimized for years. 
As an example UpdatePasswordController only responsible for updating password,
AuthController only responsible for authentication.
I prefer you to reserch some [MVC best practices](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.best-practices)